# Find an example of a closed, achronal set $S$ in Minkowski spacetime such that $J^+(S)$ is not closed

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, causality, topology

This is one of the exercises on Wald's *General Relativity*:

> **Chapter 8, Problem 8.b** Find an example of a closed, achronal set $S$ in Minkowski spacetime such that $J^+(S)$ is not closed. (Hint: Consider a noncompact subset of a null plane).

I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of years, but I haven't managed to find an example yet. Due to other results in the same chapter, I know $S$ cannot be compact, but then it seems to me that any issues with $J^+(S)$ would need to occur close to infinity and perhaps at infinity, which is not a portion of Minkowski spacetime. If the problem occurred elsewhere, it would seem to me that it would be possible to construct an example with $S$ compact. Hence, the situation seems paradoxical to me.

How is it possible to get out of this conundrum? Alternatively, what is an example of $S$?

I know of the homework policy of this website, but since this is an exercise focused on a conceptual counterexample rather than on a calculation I believe the question is on topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally what is used to find singularity theorems, particularly evident in Penrose's and Wall's theorems. Let $I$ be a codimension-2 achronal surface with a non-compact boundary $\partial I$. Then, allowing the future expansion along the inward pointing null $I$-orthogonal congruence to be negative at $\partial I$, i.e. $\theta |_{\partial I}<0$, assuming the null energy condition and assuming no caustics or conjugate points due to some "unphysical" phenomena (the latter condition is irrelevant here), the null congruence must generate a compact null hypersurface (called a light-sheet due to Bousso), so that it encounters a caustic (see this from the Raychaudari equation). However, that would imply that evolving the Cauchy slice $\Sigma $ containing $I$ upto a certain time-slice, a non-compact $I$ would become compact. However, due to global hyperbolicity, this is not allowed (see why). Therefore, the light-sheet generating $J^{+}(I)$ must not be closed, and therefore $J^{+}(I)$ is also not closed. Not sure if this is generally what you are asking, since I think they consider a null plane subset (like in the hint), but if this is a suitable answer, then good. Otherwise, I will try and make sense of the question if you want me to expand on it.